# Spring websocket with stomp: private message to multiple instances of same user

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket

I am using Springwebsockets with the STOMP protocol over Websockets, and i am using the in memory borker. I want to send messages to specific users.
On the client side i subscribe to a private topic:

```
stompClient.subscribe('/user/topic/private', function(greeting){ 
});
```

And i send the message like this:

```
stompClient.send("/user/"+ user +"/topic/private", {}, message);
```

This all works fine and i don't have to do anything on the server. But when i log in twice with the same user (eg different browsers, one desktop and one mobile), it doesn't work like i expected. I would expect that the private message ends up in both the browser. However it only seems to end up in the current browser.
Is there any better way to do this kind of private messaging? Or did i misunderstand how the private channel works?

Comment: is your `user` authenticated?

Comment: yes my users are authenticated

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
@SendToUser(value = "your destination",broadcast = true)
public String handleException(Message message) {
    //your logic goes here
    return message; // this will be sent to user
}
```

Comment: True, but i guess i would be using an application destination then and not an application destination?

Comment: what does it mean?

Comment: How i understand it, a user destination works automatically. So if i send /user/<username>/topic/private, it ends up automatically at the user (if the user is subscribed to the topic off course). So for my example i didn't need to write any java code. See section 25.4.11 http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-stomp-handle-annotations. I think this sentence 'If the user has more than one session, by default all of the sessions subscribed to the given destination are targeted.' is something i should look into more and experiment a bit